# Anchors do not work

Tags: .net, winforms

Situation: 
[alt text http://lh4.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/S-1xy6gvB0I/AAAAAAAADNc/RRH5DpGnics/s800/Capture1.png](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/S-1xy6gvB0I/AAAAAAAADNc/RRH5DpGnics/s800/Capture1.png)

In A form I have a TableLayoutPanel(Dock= Fill) and a label (which parent is the Form, not the tablelayoutPanel) which anchors are set to Top+Bottom+Left+Right.

Now, when I run this form and rezise it, the label does not center itself in the Form, as I expected.

Workarounds?

Comment: Set your `Anchor` to `None`. That worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting anchors on more than 1 corner will try resize the label unless you only set 1 corner to anchor to.

If you set `AutoSize` to `false` and change the `TextAlign` to `MiddleCenter` on the label, the text will stay centered, but this may be undesirable as the labels dimensions would change.

The workaround is to capture the `Resize` event of the `Form` and set the location of the Label manually *(not tested)*. This will mean you don't need to set `AutoSize` to false and you won't need to set the anchors.

```
void OnResize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Point pos = new Point((this.Width/2) - (Label.Width / 2), 
     (this.Height/2) - (Label.Height/2));
   Label.Location = pos;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the label autosize set to true - I'm pretty sure that's what's causing the problem.

change it to false.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to have no anchors on the label. Since an anchor will try and maintain distance from the edge your setup will cause the label to grow with the form. Unfortunately this will conflict with the AutoSize setting which will want to keep the label the same size.

By having no anchors the label is free to *move* rather than resize and it will remain proportionally the correct distance from the forms edges.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `Anchor` property causes the control to attempt to keep a constant distance from the specified edges. So if you shrink the form, the label will still maintain its distance from `Top` and `Left` and should therefore not remain centered.

I actually think that if you want the label to stay centered, you should set its `Anchor` property to **`None`**, *not* to `Top, Bottom, Left, Right`.

Now, if you are going to be changing the text of the label, here's a compromise:

1. Set your label's `Anchor` property to `None`. This will keep it centered.
2. Set your label's `AutoSize` property to **`false`**. This will allow you to specify a constant size.
3. Set the size of the label to something substantially bigger than you'll need for whatever text you want to display. Center this resulting "bloated label" on your form.
4. Set the `TextAlign` property of your label to `MiddleCenter`.

In effect, what this gives you is a rectangle that is always centered in your form, inside of which is some text consistently centered within that rectangle.

Comment: however, if I change the text, it became uncentered.

Comment: @serhio: I see. Take a look at my updated answer; I've suggested a compromise that I think will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set [`AutoSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autosize.aspx) to false.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will center itself at all.
When you resize a form, only the right and bottom will move, so if you have your anchor on all 4 sides, then just the right and bottom portions of the label (or any control) will follow, and leave the left and top alone.